What type of radiation does Io experience?
I've read that Io (the Galilean moon) experiences unusually strong radiation due to Jupiter's intense magnetic field. This astronomy.com article says that 3600 rem (= 36 Sv), which would be deadly to humans. What type of radiation (e.g. $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, etc.) is this?

Mostly high energy charged particles (electrons and protons) captured and accelerated by Jupiter's magnetic field. There is also oxygen and sulfur ions from Io's volcanos. Gamma and x-rays are produced as secondary radiation when particles collide with Oi.

@Woody Is Oi the Mirror Universe version of Io? ;)

@PM2Ring ... I believe the correct term is Oy vey    ;o)

@PM2Ring Well ChatGPT says so...but it also seems to think that Io was made up by Star Trek

Good question but this is a better fit in Astronomy.SE

Io orbits deep within Jupiter's radiation belts and is exposed to many different forms of ionizing radiation. Whilst a lot is known, our understanding of the Jupiter radiation environment is far from complete. There are gaps in our knowledge and the intense radiation environment itself causes problems with measurement.
Detected types of radiation in the vicinity of Io include:
electrons at a range of energies >21MeV,
ionized oxygen at a range of energies >640MeV,
ionized sulphur at a range of energies >16Mev,
protons and possibly ionized helium
https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1029/2020JA028925
the oxygen and sulphur are thought to originate from sulphur dioxide vented from Io directly into the radiation belts.

"the oxygen and sulphur are thought to originate from sulphur dioxide vented from Io directly into the radiation belts.". Minor point: More reduced specues (S2O, elemental S) also exist around Io's volcanoes. They are missing on Earth due to oxidation by our atmosphere.

The radiation in Jupiter's radiation belt is mostly solar wind and sulfur oxides from Io that have been broken down, ionized, and accelerated.
An accelerated electron is functionally β radiation, and the solar wind has α particles in it, but the rest of it doesn't fit cleanly into the α/β/γ system.
You're looking at fast protons (which I suppose is fairly similar to neutron flux), plus fast sulfur and oxygen nuclei. At those energies, what you're really going to get is sort of like walking into the beam of a particle accelerator. The damaging radiation isn't directly from a fast sulfur nucleus hitting you, but rather when that nucleus crashes into a metal surface or the exterior of your space suit, the atoms break and recombine sort of randomly, and generate a variety of particles and rays (most likely x-rays, maybe a little gamma) in the process. There is science about how particles act during these kinds of collisions, but frankly it's over my head. Suffice to say it'd be bad for you in a number interesting ways.
